# parse text file to find lines which contain a date after 05/05/2011

Tags: date, emacs

I could like to be able to list the line no.s in a file which contain a date, in the format dd,mm,yy, which is greater than 05/05/11

the file in question is prolog source code - the dates form part of a comment indicating when the modification after the comment was made

I'm using emacs, so thought an emacs solution would be the obvious way forward but willing to think more laterally if need be

a typical line of interest would be:

```
4.00    21/10/12    Modified to incorporate proportional match tolerances
```

I would like to report the file and line no. e.g.

```
filename         line no.
my_source_1.pl   37
```

or alternatively, just being able to step through the file using `Regexp I-search` highlighting each dd/mm/yy that is greater than 05/05/2011 would be very useful

Comment: See:  http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook -- e.g., `(time-to-days (date-to-time "Tue, 27-Sep-83 12:35:59 EST")` . . . .  Go to the applicable point in your buffer and `re-search-forward` or `re-search-backward` with the proper regexp . . .

Comment: unfortunately this comment is too cryptic for me - but I have the feeling the solution is in there somewhere

Comment: Have you tried `M-x grep`? Just give it a regexp such as this: `[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+`. You might also need to use the switch `E`, depending on your `grep` command. This works for me (I use Cygwin `grep`): `M-x grep RET`, then enter `grep --color -E -nH -e [0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+ *.el` - I had to add the `-E`.